# jQuery on ASP page with master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I wanna know how to implement a confim message before deleting a row in a gridview but without postback to server I know I need to use jQuery but i dont know how.(i select a checkbox in row gridview and press the delete button to delete, if nonoe of the rows got sleceted i want to display an alert message)
this is my aspx page:

http://pastebin.com/WVTXQx1s

and this is the c# code:

http://pastebin.com/cwAhb49F

Comment: Post relevant rendered HTML here please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dialog function of jQuery from here: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation

Your code may look something like this:

```
$('#deletebuttonid').Click((function() {
$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
  resizable: false,
  height:140,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Delete all items": function() {
      // Call your asp.net delete function here
    },
    Cancel: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
});
);
```

Then in your body:

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0;">        </span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
```